# What's the counterpart to "enemy"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If your "enemies" are those you want to harm or kill, what's the word for those you want to support or enable?

Comment: Friends?.......

Comment: If you think my answers helps or answers your queries, you can accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I had to repeat all the time I spent searching thesauruses and regenerate all the negative results in the question for you to think I'm not a waste of time - tho if this is like other SE sites if I'd done that most readers would have lost the question in the research.  But the short summary is the obvious one; I didn't find a word with that meaning.  The sentence was "I don’t understand either the racism or the choice to attack perceived enemies rather than rather than support and enable perceived ________"; https://twitter.com/ShadSterling/status/1536573175177306112

Comment: But my guess is that we don't have any word for that, because we've been so much more focused on harming eachother than helping eachother that it just doesn't come up often enough to need a word

Answer (score 4):

**allies**:

> a person, group, or nation that is associated with another or others for some common cause or purpose: Canada and the United States were allies in World War II.
>
> to associate or connect by some mutual relationship, as resemblance or friendship.

[Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ally)

Comment: Strictly speaking, *allies* are those who are joined together for a common cause or purpose. OP asks about “those who you want to support or enable” which could be your allies but could also be a third party- maybe a party you and your allies are trying to help.